# Caliburn Micro - UI not updated second time

Tags: wpf, data-binding, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I'm working on a WPF project that is using Caliburn Micro. I am running into a problem where the controls in the View are not getting updated the second time the View is opened. The first time the data binding works fine.

When I step through the ViewModel the second time the View is invoked I can see that the data bound properties are getting new values and invoking NotifyOfPropertyChange() but the change is not reflected in the UI. Any ideas? My View inherits `PropertyChangedBase()`

Below are my properties in view model

```
public string Info
{
    get { return _info; }
    set { _info = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Info); }
}

public IEnumerable<ComponentInfo> BondableComponents
{
    get { return _bondableComponents; }
    set { _bondableComponents = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => BondableComponents); }
}
```

and Xaml

```
<TextBox Name="Info" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" IsReadOnly="True"/>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding BondableComponents}">
```

Comment: Can you show the code which is opening and closing your View?

Comment: Are you populating data in OnInitialize instead of OnActivate or OnViewLoaded?

Answer (score -1):

```
BindableCollection<ComponentInfo> Bondable
```

Should be used if you new items to appear on an update...
--edit--
answered on GitHub.

Comment: The OP is already raising property notification events, if the collection is replaced with another collection the UI should still update, there is no mention of adding/removing items from a collection.. what does a bindable collection do to fix this issue?